# Use of range in ruby array access

Tags: ruby, arrays, indexing

I found the following code in the homebrew code base:

```
reject{|arg| arg[0..0] == '-'}
```

Apparently this will remove the element of the array (self) if the element starts with a '-'.  My question is why on earth would you need to specify the 0th element of arg in this way, arg[0..0] instead of just specifying arg[0] ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because Ruby versions prior to 1.9 return *integers* (character codes), not characters, from single-element indexing into strings. Like so:

```
> "abc"[0]
#=> 97
> "abc"[0..0]
#=> "a"
> "abc"[0] == 'a'
#=> false
> "abc"[0..0] == 'a'
#=> true
```

As of Ruby 1.9, there would be no difference between unsing `arg[0..0]` and `arg[0]` in your example.